# Unable to Find String in a file and populate it using Inno Setup?

Tags: arrays, string, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have `demo.properties` file from this I'm able to load file and iterate to get all values present in it.

```
hibernate.connection.username=jack
hibernate.connection.password=queen
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/cabinet
```

But when I get Line 1 (able to get line by line but unable to get specific string) and i want to  populate jack and store into username String similarly queen into password String and localhost into database String.This is my code/logic to get values.

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
var  

  xmlInhalt: TArrayOfString;  
  k : Integer;
  CurrentLine : String;
  Uname : String;  
   Password : String;
   HostName : String;
   STR : String;                        

begin
          LoadStringsFromFile('C:\demo.properties', xmlInhalt);
          for k:=0 to GetArrayLength(xmlInhalt)<>-1 do
          begin
            CurrentLine := xmlInhalt[k];
            MsgBox(CurrentLine, mbError, MB_OK);
            if (Pos('hibernate.connection.username=', CurrentLine) <>-1 ) then
                begin
                              MsgBox(CurrentLine, mbError, MB_OK);
                    Uname := Pos('://', CurrentLine);
                    STR :=IntToStr(Uname);    
                    STR :=IntToStr(Length('://')); 
                    Password := Pos(':1', CurrentLine);
                    HostName :=Password -Uname;                  

              end;    
         end; 
end;
```

please Help me to get my requirement.Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `TStrings` class had published `NameValueSeparator` and `Values` properties, I would suggest using it. But it hasn't, so here's a code to workaround (it uses `TArrayOfString`, but it would be easy to modify it for the `TStrings` class):

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
function TryGetValue(const Strings: TArrayOfString; const Name: string;
  out Value: string): Boolean;
var
  S: string;
  P: Integer;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  { loop through the array }
  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Strings) - 1 do
  begin
    { store the currently iterated string into a local variable }
    S := Strings[I];
    { try to get position of the name value separator ('='in this case) }
    P := Pos('=', S);
    { if the separator was found on this line, and a text on the left of }
    { it matches (case insensitively) the input Name parameter value, we }
    { found what we were looking for, so return True and the rest of the }
    { text after the found separator }
    if (P <> 0) and (CompareText(Copy(S, 1, P - 1), Name) = 0) then
    begin
      Value := Copy(S, P + 1, MaxInt);
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

{ do note, that this function may not conform the RFC 3986 specification; }
{ preferred way should be e.g. InternetCrackUrl, but with this particular }
{ scheme (jdbc:jtds:sqlserver) it didn't crack the URL properly }
function GetHostName(const URL: string): string;
var
  P: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  P := Pos('://', URL);
  if P <> 0 then
  begin
    Result := Copy(URL, P + 3, MaxInt);
    P := Pos('/', Result);
    if P = 0 then
      P := MaxInt;
    Result := Copy(Result, 1, P - 1);
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var  
  URL: string;
  HostName: string;
  UserName: string;
  Password: string;
  StrArray: TArrayOfString;
begin
  if LoadStringsFromFile('C:\File.txt', StrArray) then
  begin
    TryGetValue(StrArray, 'hibernate.connection.url', URL);
    HostName := GetHostName(URL);
    TryGetValue(StrArray, 'hibernate.connection.username', UserName);
    TryGetValue(StrArray, 'hibernate.connection.password', Password);
    MsgBox(Format(
      'HostName: %s' + #13#10 + 'UserName: %s' + #13#10 + 'Password: %s', [
      HostName, UserName, Password]
    ), mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: TLama,Everything is working fine,HostName should be only localhost not entire line.how to extract that.

Comment: Thank you TLama for your effort to solve this,Currently  HostName: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/cabinet     for that only need localhost  name. How to get substring.

Comment: Wait for a while, please. I will post a separate Q&A where I show how to crack an URL because it should not be about plain `Copy` (even if that work).

Comment: TLama,can you tell me how to get that value from that entire string.

Comment: See the update. I was about to show you how to crack an URL properly, but for some reason the `InternetCrackUrl` function (which I was expecting to be preferred for this task) cannot handle schemes with colons (it succeeds but the scheme is cut by the first colon and the returned host name component remains empty).